# Add titles to ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

With the help of [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/) I have created a PagerAdapter for my Android App.

Now I like to add a title to each page (like in the Play Store).
I found this library: http://viewpagerindicator.com/
But I can't find out how to implement it in my app or how to use it.

Can someone please explain the usage to me?

Here's the code of my PagerAdapter, if it is needed:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;

        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.layout.farleft;
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.layout.left;
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.layout.middle;
                break;
            case 3:
                resId = R.layout.right;
                break;
            case 4:
                resId = R.layout.farright;
                break;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the method `getPageTitle()`? ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageTitle%28int%29 )

Comment: Ok, I can find out the title of the page with this method. But I like to add a "title-bar" at the top of the ViewPager. Similar to that one in the Google Play Store when switching through the categories. Do you know, what I mean?

Comment: Check Commonsware's answer. I thought you have a `PagerTitleStrip` in your layout already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now I like to add a title to each page (like in the Play Store)

`PagerTabStrip` and `PagerTitleStrip` are in the Android Support package, where you got `ViewPager` from. Simply add one of those as a child of your `ViewPager`, with `android:layout_gravity` indicating whether you want the strip on the top or bottom. Then, as Luksprog indicated, add `getPageTitle()` to your `PagerAdapter`.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Indicator) demonstrating the use of `PagerTabStrip`.

> But I can't find out how to implement it in my app or how to use it.

Basic instructions are on the page that you linked to. Add one of the ViewPagerIndicator widgets to your layout, positioned where you want it (e.g., use a `vertical` `LinearLayout` to stack one above your `ViewPager`). Sometime after you call `setAdapter()` on the `ViewPager`, call `setViewPager()` on the indicator widget, supplying it your `ViewPager`. Once again, you will also need to implement `getPageTitle()` on your `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: Now I've added the PagerTitleStrip. That's what I needed :) But how exactly do I use the getPageTitle-method? I have added it to my PagerAdapter but I get lots of errors. And I'm wondering how this would find out my titles if they aren't definded.

Comment: @cShock_: You can see `getPageTitle()` in the sample project that I linked to. You just return some `String` given the `position` of the page. In my case, I am building one out of a string resource and the position number itself.

Comment: It works, when I just modify the getPageTitle-method to return "test". Now every title is "test". But when I use your implementation it will give me a StackOverflowError. Am I doing it right, when I override this method in my PagerAdapter?

Comment: @cShock_: "But when I use your implementation it will give me a StackOverflowError" -- I fail to see how, unless you are somehow calling itself by accident. "Am I doing it right, when I override this method in my PagerAdapter?" -- I have no way to answer that.

Comment: Sorry. I will sign up at github to show you the code. One moment please.

Comment: @cShock_: Well, of course your commented-out code would result in a `StackOverflowError` -- you are calling `getPageTitle()` from `getPageTitle()`.

Comment: Hm yes^^ But now I found a easier way: I created an array with all my titles and now I can get an index by the position. Thank you for your help and patience :)

Answer (score 2):

Today, I find the library PagerSlidingTabStrip a much better choice than the android's default one.

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

PS: Sorry for posting as Answer, I don't have enough reputation for commenting.

Comment: Once you do, please move this to a comment on the question. :)